# jersey 2 constraintvalidator called twice

Tags: validation, javabeans, cdi, jersey-2.0

Using Jersy 2 on Glassfish 4.
I have a custom ConstraintValidator that is being called to validate a bean parameter.

The `ConstraintValidator` is correctly injected with Jersey resources using `@Context`. (Changed @Context to @Inject to solve problem with resources being null when ConstraintValidator is called twice by the system.)

Problem the `isValid()` method is called twice I can see the logging being printed twice before the `update()` method is being called.

I added an interceptor to do some debug logging.
First the constraintvalidator.isValid() is called then my Interceptor then constraintvalidator.isValid() is called again and then only my REST resource method.

(This class does not contain any injected resources.)

```
public class StudyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<StudyCheck, StudyBeanREST> {

  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(StudyValidator.class);

  @Override
  public void initialize(StudyCheck constraintAnnotation) {
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(StudyBeanREST study, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
    log.info("Validating study: " + study);
    Integer version = study.getVersion();
    if(version == null || version < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

The annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER,ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = {StudyValidator.class})
public @interface StudyCheck {
  String message() default "{error.version}";

  Class<?>[] groups() default {};

  Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

And where I use my annotation:

```
  @PUT
  @RolesAllowed({"management"})
  public StudyBeanREST update(@StudyCheck StudyBeanREST study) throws RecordNotFoundException, UpdateNotAllowedException {
    Study updated = studyEJB.update(study.getJpa());
    study.setJpa(updated);
    return study;
  }
```

Comment: When you say the injected resources are null, it's not clear what you're referring to.  There are no injected resources in your example.  Did you mean the method arguments?

Comment: No, this example has not injected resources, but the isValid() method is called twice (as well as the constraintvalidator's init method) with this example and other usecases. The resoureces I am injecting is the REST ejb resource to get access to the persistence unit.

Comment: A though: Is the EJB container doing the validation and then the Jersey servlet as well ?